# ASP.net MVC: Accessing Google GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker returns access denied error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, youtube-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to upload an video to my YouTube account with the following code in my ActionResult in my asp.net MVC project:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Upload([Bind(Include = " Title, Description")] HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile, Videos videos)
    { 
var credential = AuthYouTube();
YouTubeService youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new 

YouTubeService.Initializer()
                {
                    ApplicationName = "app-name",
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential
                });

// Do Stuff with the video here.
}}
```

The AuthYouTube() looks like this (the same controller):

```
 public UserCredential AuthYouTube()
    {
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/YT/client_secret.json");
        UserCredential credential;
        try{

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
                    // authenticated user's account.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
                    "username@domain.com",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(Server.MapPath("~/Content/YT"),true)
                ).Result;
            };
            return credential;
        }
        catch(EvaluateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

I have stored my client_secret.json that I downloaded from Google Developer Console inside the [project]/Content/YT. (Also tried inside the /App_Data folder.

When uploading the debugger is showing the folowwing message:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
```

Place where the error occures:

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
```

StackStrace:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +115
   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task) +78
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:59

[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) +4472256
   Project.Controllers.VideosController.AuthYouTube() in d:\dev\Development\project\project\Controllers\VideosController.cs:133
   project.Controllers.VideosController.Upload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile, Videos videos) in d:\dev\project\project\Controllers\VideosController.cs:71
```

What is the reason of this?
- Google API?
- folder / IIS rights?

**Update 01-02-2016**

Could it be some access error on the API side?
If not, could somebody please provide me the steps to grand the right IIS rights, still get the error after giving folder permissions.

Running the following code DOES create the folder as intended inside my App_Data, but also returns the same 'Access denied' error. The folder is empty.

```
        var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Drive.Api.Auth.Store");

        // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                     , scopes
                                                                                     , userName
                                                                                     , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                     , new FileDataStore(path,true)).Result;
```

Could somebody please explain how to get this working?

Comment: add a check that it can find the file filePath  and access it.

Comment: @dalmo  Did that allready. The filepath (stream) excists. More actions to do?

Comment: make sure that you have access to write to that directory.  sounds to me like filedatastore cant create a file.  Give Admin Rights to IIS User.

Comment: Checked my IIS user (gave it rights on the folders) but it is stil; not working. Could you provide more details in setting the right? don't know if it are the folder/iis rights, could it maybe be something on the API side?

Comment: I am not an IIS expert.  However I have seen this error, I just cant remember what I did to fix it.  I tagged IIS in your question with luck someone will IIS knowledge be able to shed more light on this for us.

Comment: Also: it when running my Youtube insert code inside your console application from your github demo there is an popup of Google to sign in. In my own asp.net application i don't have this popup when using the same code as in your console app. Could this be the problem?

 (link: https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/YouTube/YouTube-Data/Daimto-YouTube-Data/Daimto-YouTube-Data)

Comment: if you don't change the userName option then its only going to pop up once as it will continue to use the same filedatastore in %appdata% or in your case where ever filePath  is pointing to.

Comment: After reading the documentation again, i found a way to use the API. added an comment with my implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After ready the documentation again I found a way to get access to the API and upload my videos to YouTube. I hope I can clarify the way i did this.

How i did this:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc

**Create an callback controller:**

```
using Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4.Controllers
{
    public class AuthCallbackController : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.Controllers.AuthCallbackController
    {
        protected override Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.FlowMetadata FlowData
        {
            get { return new AppFlowMetadata(); }
        }
    }
}
```

**Create class and fill-in the credentials:**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;    
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4
{
    public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
    {
        private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/clientsecret.json")),
                });

        public override string AuthCallback
        {
             get { return @"/AuthCallback/Upload"; }
        }

        public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
        {
            // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
            // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
            // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
            // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
            var user = controller.Session["user"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = Guid.NewGuid();
                controller.Session["user"] = user;
            }
            return user.ToString();

        }

        public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
        {
            get { return flow; }
        }
    }
}
```

In my ActionResult I set the **YoutubeService**. the creating of my video take place inside my **Upload POST**

**Your own controller (mine is for the /upload action):**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
           var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);
            if (result.Credential != null)
            {
                var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                    ApplicationName = "name",
                });
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
            }        
        }
```

**For uploading logic see:** https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

**Set redirect URL in Google Developers console**

In the Google Developers Console set the Authorized redirect URIs value to something like (my controller is called videos): http://www.domainname.com/Videos/Upload

**Using a single oAuth account **

Insted of saving the client id (GUID, see GetUserId inside AppFlowMetadata file) inside my session I now use one single id so I could use the same token/responsive for all the users.